# why is mysql not returning correct order for varchar of floats?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I have a column `version` which is `varchar` but contains `double` values.
when I try to get the latest (max) version I get incorrect results. But when I do min, I get correct result.

How is the ordering of varchar columns containing double determined?

Here is the content of my table;

```
    mysql> Desc Application;
    +---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | version | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

    mysql> select * from Application;
    +----+---------+
    | id | version |
    +----+---------+
    |  1 | 0.0.0   |
    |  2 | 0.0.1   |
    |  3 | 0.0.2   |
    |  4 | 0.1.0   |
    |  5 | 0.1.1   |
    |  6 | 0.1.2   |
    |  7 | 1.0.0   |
    |  8 | 1.0.1   |
    |  9 | 1.1.1   |
    | 10 | 8.7.3   |
    | 11 | 10.29.0 |
    +----+---------+
    11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    select max(version) from application;
+--------------+
| max(version) |
+--------------+
| 8.7.3        |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version from application
    -> ORDER BY version DESC
    -> LIMIT 1;
+---------+
| version |
+---------+
| 8.7.3   |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select min(version) from application;
+--------------+
| min(version) |
+--------------+
| 0.0.0        |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: A varchar can only contain character strings. There is no such thing as "double values" in a varchar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget the idea that these are floats. MySQl sees them as character strings because that's what you've told it.

Sorting by **character** order, `8` is the largest, and `0` is the minimum, so your results are correct.

If you want MySQL to sort by numerical order, give it numerical fields. Alternatively, right-align and zero-pad your subfields - `08.07.03` is less than `10.29.00`

Comment: ok got it. is there a built in function in sql which can take varchar and return float value?

Comment: MySQL will generally coerce to whatever it needs, and you can force the issue with `CAST` or `CONVERT` if you need to, but these are still not floats. Numbers only have one decimal point at most.